# Wagtail: embedded media (but not through a RichTextField)

Tags: vimeo-api, wagtail

Wagtail supports embedded media (e.g., Vimeo or YouTube videos) in a really cool way, but the only way I've seen it done is through using a RichTextField and getting to the interface for embedding the media through RTF widget.

It seems to me that there should be something similar to ImageChooserPanel to allow for embedded media objects to be part of models WITHOUT having them be in a RichTextField, but I haven't seen anything in the documentation to that effect.

What am I missing?   Any pointer to docs or a working example would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with a plain URLField on the page model:

```
class HomePage(Page):
    ...
    video_url = models.URLField("Video URL", blank=True)
```

Then on your template, use the 'embed' template filter:

```
{% load wagtailembeds_tags %}

{{ page.video_url|embed }}
```

or to specify a maximum width:

```
{% load wagtailembeds_tags %}

{{ page.video_url|embed:1000 }}
```

Comment: This got the job done, but I was hoping that somehow I could use the back-end operation that the RTF widget does to scrape the external URL for metadata, poster image, etc.    Is there a way to do that?